# TRUNCATE Table + Zend Framework

Tags: php, sql, database, zend-framework

I do this:

```
$data = array('coords'   => $district->getCoords(),
    'id'       => $district->getId(),
    'fid'      => $district->getFid(),
    'wijziging'=> $district->getWijziging(),
    'nieuwnr'  => $district->getNieuwnr(),
    'naam'     => $district->getNaam(),
    'wijk'     => $district->getWijk(),
    'wijknr'   => $district->getWijknr(),
    'objectid' => $district->getObjectid(),
    'area'     => $district->getArea(),
    'len'      => $district->getLen(),
);


$this->_dbTable->insert($data);
```

_dbTable -> references to my table 'Districts'.

Now I want to clear the table first before I insert the data.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try to get the adapter if you really need to truncate the table

```
$this->_dbTable->getAdapter()->query('TRUNCATE TABLE '.$this->_dbTable->info(Zend_Db_Table::NAME));
```

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
$this->_dbTable->delete("1=1");
```

Should take care of your problem. 1=1 will match all records thus deleting them. There is no truncate method in Zend_Db or PDO as far as I know.

@Rikesh is right take a moment to review the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) you will get much better help after following that.

Comment: When I do that:
$this->_dbTable->delete("1=1");      
$this->_dbTable->insert($data);

And when I check my database I see that there's only the last row in it...

Comment: Well it should be there if you insert it after the delete? I am positive this will erase everything in a table. You MUST be inserting after the delete.

Answer (score 4):

Extend Zend_Db_Table_Abstract and add:

```
/**
 * Remove all contents of the table
 * @return this
 */
public function truncate()
{
    $this->getAdapter()->query('TRUNCATE TABLE `' . $this->_name . '`');

    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Zend Framework 2 with tableGateway, the process is very similar.

```
    $query = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter()->query('TRUNCATE TABLE '.$this->tableGateway->getTable());
    $query->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

namespace MyNamespace\Db\Sql;

use Zend\Db\Adapter\ParameterContainer;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Platform\PlatformInterface;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\Driver\DriverInterface;
use Zend\Db\Sql\AbstractPreparableSql;
use Zend\Db\Sql\TableIdentifier;

class Truncate extends AbstractPreparableSql
{
    /**@#+
     * @const string
     */
    const SPECIFICATION_TRUNCATE = 'truncate';
    /**@#-*/

    /**
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $specifications = [
        self::SPECIFICATION_TRUNCATE => /* @lang SQL */ 'TRUNCATE TABLE %1$s',
    ];

    /**
     * @var string|TableIdentifier
     */
    protected $table = '';

    /**
     * @param null|string|TableIdentifier $table
     */
    public function __construct($table = null)
    {
        if ($table) {
            $this->table($table);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param  string|TableIdentifier $table
     * @return self
     */
    public function table($table)
    {
        $this->table = $table;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * @param  PlatformInterface       $platform
     * @param  DriverInterface|null    $driver
     * @param  ParameterContainer|null $parameterContainer
     * @return string
     */
    protected function processTruncate(PlatformInterface $platform, DriverInterface $driver = null, ParameterContainer $parameterContainer = null)
    {
        return sprintf(
            $this->specifications[static::SPECIFICATION_TRUNCATE],
            $this->resolveTable($this->table, $platform, $driver, $parameterContainer)
        );
    }
}
```

---

```
$truncate = new Truncate('table');
return $this->getSql()->prepareStatementForSqlObject($truncate)->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

In case of Zend Framework 2/3 with tableGateway:

```
    $adapter = $this->tableGateway->getAdapter();
    $sql = 'TRUNCATE TABLE '.$this->tableGateway->getTable();
 //Or, 
    $sql = 'DELETE FROM '.$this->tableGateway->getTable();

    $adapter->query($sql)->execute();
 // Or, 
    $adapter->createStatement($sql)->execute();
```